# Angular fails to bind input text in foundation modal

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am using the angular directives for foundation provided here - http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation

I ve been looking to use a text field within one of their modal boxes. For some reason i see that it behaves properly for every angular directive except the model. After inputting anything in the text field and closing the modal window, i cant retrieve the value entered in the field within my view, the model is always undefined. See demo below 
http://plnkr.co/edit/FT1M2JjfRarZMTCwkOJG?p=preview

```
{{mytext}}
```

Doesnt yield anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the `$scope.selected` as:

```
$scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0],
    myText: ""
}
```

And your `$scope.ok` as:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected);
};
```

In your `ModalInstanceCtrl`.

This makes it easy to access the variables in the `then` function:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selected) {
    $scope.selected = selected.item;
    $scope.myText = selected.myText;
}, ...);
```

You can check out the working [**example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1GTVVpFBzyI3wCxSogsS?p=preview).